# How can I play mp4 files from a USB live iso?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, mp4

How can I play mp4 files from a USB live iso of Ubuntu 11.04?
I can mount my external hard drive, but totem wouldn't allow me to play my mp4 files. Trying to find the ubuntu restricted packages with "apt-cache search restricted" gives me nothing back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you'd have to first change your sources lists first. [Medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org/repository.php) is how I used to do it.

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

Once you've done this you should be able to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: any ideas what would be the equivalent for ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: I thought this was, sorry. Always has been a general thing in the past. This [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1689167) is marked as 'solved' for what it's worth. Hope it's some help.

Answer (score 1):

By installing [libavcodec52](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libavcodec52) [image: Install libavcodec52] from main repository or [libavcodec-extra-52](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libavcodec-extra-52) [image: Install libavcodec-extra-52] from multiverse you will be able to play standard mp4 video files with most movie players.

You can install these packages from a live USB session and keep them in a reserved space if you had set up your USB-drive for this feature.